# The equality of gradient between different calculations?

Tags: optimization

Suppose there is a problem

$$\min\limits_v\max\limits_x E(v,x).$$

$E$ is a concave function w.r.t. $x$. But w.r.t. $v$, $E$ is a convex function plus a concave function.

I can get $x^*=\arg\max\limits_x E(v,x)=\phi(v)$.

Since $E$ is a convex function plus a concave function, it is hard `for me` to find the minimal even all stationary points.

If I fix $x$, then I calculate the partial derivative $\frac{\partial E}{\partial v}=f(x,v)$. Then I plug $x^*=\phi(v)$ into $f(\phi(v),v)$.

But another case is first I plug $x^*=\phi(v)$ into $E(v,x)=E(v,\phi(v))=G(v)$. (This is more complex. ) Then I calculate the derivative of $\frac{dG}{dv}$.

My question is should $f(\phi(v),v)$ be equal to $\frac{dG}{dv}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Note that by the chain rule 
$$ G'(v) = \partial_x E\bigl(\phi(v), v\bigr)\phi'(v) + \partial_v E\bigl(\phi(v),v\bigr) = \partial_x E\bigl(\phi(v), v\bigr)\phi'(v) + f\bigl(\phi(v),v\bigr) $$
So $G' = f\bigl(\phi(\cdot), \cdot\bigr)$ only if $\partial_x E(\phi(\cdot),\cdot) \phi' = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. $x^*=\phi(v), {\partial _xE(v,x^*)}=0={\partial_x E(v,\phi(v))}=0$.                    So $\partial \limits_x E(\phi(v),v)= 0$ always be true?

Comment: So $$\partial _x E(\phi(v),v)= 0$$ always be true?